# Dúvida sobre como usar corretamente o SOpt?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Atualmente estou lendo alguns livros sobre banco de dados e estou frequentemente postando perguntas muito mais teóricas do práticas e quase **nenhuma** puramente sobre programação na plataforma do SOpt.

Gostaria de saber se a comunidade ver com bons olhos, usuários com esse tipo de perfil, as vezes posto perguntas bem elaboradas (típico de quem de fato leu o livro) e torço para encontrar alguém com conhecimentos suficientes para sanar minha dúvida(específica), mas as vezes os administradores fecham a pergunta ou deixa como pendente.

Caso eu esteja na comunidade errada, qual você indicariam ?

> **Meu Perfil** atual
>
> > 1. Lendo livros sobre banco de dados
> > 2. Foco em responder perguntas de concurso público
> > 3. Estou estudando sozinho e estou em busca de pessoas que também estejam estudando para trocar conhecimento
> > 4. Focado em assuntos voltados para T.I

Primeiramente peço desculpas caso a pergunta esteja fora do foco do SO meta e irei retirar caso não seja aceita.

Somente gostaria de uma orientação.

Comment: Não se preocupe, esse tipo de pergunta é exatamente o foco do Meta. Agora, pelo que vi no histórico das suas perguntas, apenas duas foram fechadas. Uma sobre aplicar o SOpt em ambiente de ensino, que realmente não faz parte do escopo do site, outra sobre exemplos da 3FN, fechada como não clara. Não tenho conhecimento para julgar se realmente não está clara, mas ainda assim é apenas uma pergunta em 14 que já fez no site. Todas as outras estão abertas, então não ficou clara a sua dúvida.

Comment: Na verdade tinha outras pendentes @AndersonCarlosWoss só que eu exclui, e tentei refazer, mas como disse elas parecem não serem bem aceitas na comunidade, por causa dos votos negativos, as vezes acontece de alguém da -1 e vem outro e da +1 mas ai fica nessa e fica balanceada em 0, as pessoas que leem parecem estar divididas(eu acho)

Comment: Reconheço que a comunidade foi criada para tratar de problemas mais práticos, e como eu tenho uma abordagem um pouco mais teórica ai surgiu essa dúvida se realmente posso está contribuindo e interagindo com o público correto.

Comment: @JonathasB.Cavalcante Não há problema algum fazer perguntas teóricas (muitas das minhas perguntas são puramente teóricas), e este tipo de perguntas costumam ser bem aceitas pela comunidade. Desde que a pergunta esteja elaborada canonicamente você não terá com que se preocupar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu dei uma olhada muito rápida nas suas perguntas. Algumas tem pontuação zero, o que não é nenhum problema, mas a maioria tem alguma pontuação positiva. Nenhuma tem pontuação negativa.

A pontuação individual de cada pergunta ou resposta é um termômetro do quanto aquela publicação se adequa ao site. Eu diria que as suas são adequadas.

Dúvidas teóricas sobre bancos de dados são bem vindas aqui, pois todo DBA que se preze deve saber como um sistema gerenciador de bases se comporta. Eu gostei das suas perguntas e até dei um voto positivo em algumas delas agora. Fique a vontade para postar mais perguntas assim sempre que quiser.